# Before Publishing my app worked fine but after publishing my app is not working

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, exception, nullpointerexception

Before publishing my app worked fine but after publishing my app is not working.

I have used Firebase. I have created two apps one for the user and one for the admin where admin can add stories and users can read it. My app worked fine before uploading to Play Store but when I downloaded from  Play Store I'm getting null pointer exception kindly help me if someone knows how to solve it.

Note:

- developed in Kotlin language
- added shai keys in Firebase.

Comment: kindly post ErrorLogcat with related code snippet... :D

Comment: Connect your device to your computer with LogCat running in Android Studio so you can get the stack trace.

Comment: my app is working fine while i run....it shows error after uploading on playstore.